# MarkLogic - search.suggest does not return any values

Tags: javascript, marklogic, search-suggestion, marklogic-10

I'm trying to use search.suggest to return me some suggestions based on a multiple range indexes in my database. So far I've tried with single string element range index, but can't figure out proper syntax I guess.

```
const search = require('/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search');
const options = 
fn.head(xdmp.unquote('<search:options xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">' +
 '<default-suggestion-source>' +
   '<range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation//S1" type="xs:string">' +
      '<json-property>title</json-property>' +
   '</range>' +
 '</default-suggestion-source>' +
'</search:options>')).root;
search.suggest("Taiw", options)
```

I've changed a bit a code snippet from here: https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/search.suggest but it does not produce any results:
[image]

I have element range index in my database with data
[image]
[image]

I've also tried to use JSON:

```
const search = require('/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search');
const options = {
  "search:options":{
   "default-suggestion-source":{
      "range":{
         "range":{
            "type":"xs:string",
            "collation":"http://marklogic.com/collation//S1",
            "element":{
               "name":"title"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}}
search.suggest("Taiw", options)
```

But I end up with:

> [javascript] XDMP-AS: (err:XPTY0004) $options as
> element(search:options)? -- Invalid coercion:
> object-node{"search:options":object-node{"default-suggestion-source":object-node{...}}}
> as element(search:options)

What am I doing wrong? Is there any setting I need to set on my database". I'm using JSON data

Comment: For the Javascript version, that does not appear to be a valid options payload. Please see example here: docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/query-options#id_38007. If You scroll down, You will see a sample of a JSON options object

Comment: PLease clarify in the post of your content is JSON or XML

Comment: @DavidEnnis-CleverLlamas.com it's JSON

Comment: In sample 1: Based on your cts.values example, I would suggest that you would reference the element name and not a json-property.       <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation//S1" 
          type="xs:string" facet="true">
      <element ns="" name="title"/>
   </range>  This is actually the direction You were going with the second version (invalid options object)

Comment: still no results after adding element range

Comment: Quite strange.  I rebuilt your entire example including fake data and range index.  in Javascript, I get no results.  In xQuery, I get expected results.

Comment: @DavidEnnis-CleverLlamas.com thank you for your help. It was an issue of name spacing xml attributes

Comment: You are very welcome.  That one stumped me. On the bright side, I looked at the samples in the rest of the JS version of search:search related items and it appears that search.suggest was the only one with a silly example in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example code is wrong.

The issue is that each of the search option elements should be in the `search` namespace. So, you either need to apply the search namespace-prefix to all of the elements:

```
const search = require('/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search');
const options = 
fn.head(xdmp.unquote('<search:options xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">' +
 '<search:default-suggestion-source>' +
   '<search:range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation//S1" type="xs:string" facet="true">' +
     '<search:element ns="" name="title"/>' +
   '</search:range>' +
 '</search:default-suggestion-source>' +
'</search:options>')).root;
search.suggest("Ta", options);
```

Or, change the declaration of the namespace not to use the `search` prefix, and then remove the `search` prefix from all of the elements:

```
const search = require('/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search');
const options = 
fn.head(xdmp.unquote('<options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">' +
 '<default-suggestion-source>' +
   '<range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation//S1" type="xs:string" facet="true">' +
     '<element ns="" name="title"/>' +
   '</range>' +
 '</default-suggestion-source>' +
'</options>')).root;
search.suggest("Ta", options);
```

In the XQuery equivalent, the example shows declaring the default (no prefix) namespace with the search namespace, and the `search` prefix was already declared when importing the module and was in-scope, so both with and without a prefix the options elements were bound to that namespace.

Comment: Cool, that works. Thanks! Although, it would be great to fix syntax issue here: https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/search.suggest\. It's a bit misleading as it does not specify search: prefix to all elements.

Comment: Agreed, I'll file a documentation bug and see if we can get that corrected. Another way to fix it is to declare the search namespace for unprefixed and for search prefix: `<search:options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" xmlns:search="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">` and then if your options element do or don't have `search:` they will still be in that namespace.